# "am having/ are having" or "have"?

Tags: grammaticality

Which of the following is grammatically correct?

> I am having OR I have.
>
> We/they/you are having OR we/they/you have.

For eg.

> **I have/ We have** a problem that I/we can't seem get rid of.

OR

> **I am having/ We are having** a problem that I/we can't seem get rid of.

Comment: You should be asking this on [ell.se]

Comment: Suggested migration to [ell.se]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Grammatically*, they are both fine.

In English *usage*, it depends which variety of English you are talking about.

In British English, there are some uses where *am/is/are having* is idiomatic, for example:

- for some mental states or personal experiences:

> I'm having second thoughts about going out tonight.
>
> He's having a panic attack
>
> They're having fun.

- where *have* has the meaning *being the host for* (either an event or a visitor), and with a sense of future intent, so:

> We are having a party next month.
>
> We are having our cousins to stay next week.

But for most uses of *have* we don't use the progressive.

In British English

> We're having a problem

is possible, but means something like *we are experiencing a problem*, rather than the neutral *there is a problem*: it carries a sense that we are somehow personally involved in or affected by the problem.

My impression is that in Indian English *we are having* is much more widely used.